# Powershell Loop Freezing, waiting for enter when there is no input needed

Tags: scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a powershell script that is looping while connecting to server, and checking to see if some jobs are done. It checks, sleeps for 60 seconds and then checks again. The script will keep checking until no jobs are found.

However, every now and then, the script just hangs for no reason. If I hit enter, it starts up again. There is no input in this entire script. At no point do I grab anything from the host. Why is it doing this and how can I prevent it? It's no good for automation if I have to randomly hit enter for no reason.

BTW, I am using Powershell 2.0.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I get a feeling that Richard hit it on the head. I most likely had Powershell in select mode by clicking on the window. If I hit escape, I can see that the Title Bar no longer says Select: at the beginning. So far it's been good, although it's a random error. I'll post again if it turns out to still happen.

Comment: We would need to see what you ARE doing, because it seems almost certain that some command within your loop is causing this. If you *are* clicking on the (blue part of the) window itself, that definitely would cause that. Hit "Esc" next time instead.

Comment: That's what I tried (hitting esc), and I think that may have been it. Stupid mistake on my part for not noticing. As for the script, I'm loading a custom .net DLL and using its classes. They all work fine. The only powershell cmdlets I am using are Start-Sleep and Write-Host.

Answer (score 5):

Is it running in a Console window? If so have you managed to start a select (with the mouse): the title should have changed to start "Select".

When selecting the console window is frozen... and if only one character cell is selected it can be hard to spot...

Comment: I see what you're saying! Thank you. Let me see if this changes it. There is a chance I have one cell selected. I never noticed the select in the titlebar before. Thank you so much!